# WooCommerce - How can I add multiple, products to cart using ajax with same add-to-cart-Button?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to use ajax to add multiple, different products to cart with one button click. The AddToCart-Button is living in SHOP before pagination.
Ajax request sent multiple for example if I select 6 products and add to cart at a time the Ajax request sent 6 times and only 2 or 3 products added into cart not all of them. Everytime I add multiple products the code will add few of them.

and another bug is when I clicked add to cart for multiple product order the loader isn't work and cart NOT updated instantly I have to refresh the page so the cart will update and show me number of products on Cart Icon you can check on all functionality on the website: [My Website](https://myprojectstaging.net/development/firstline/store/)

you have to login on it for using shop page here is the credentials:
login url:> https://myprojectstaging.net/development/firstline/my-account/

> user: retailer 
>  pass: myprojec_firstline.!

This is my `function.php` file code:

```
    function woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    $product_id = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_product_id', absint($_POST['product_id']));
    $quantity = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_quantity', absint($_POST['quantity']));
    $passed_validation = apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', true, $product_id, $quantity);
    $product_status = get_post_status($product_id);

    if ($passed_validation && WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity) && 'publish' === $product_status) {

        
            do_action('woocommerce_ajax_added_to_cart', $product_id);
        
        if ('yes' === get_option('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_add')) {
            wc_add_to_cart_message(array($product_id => $quantity), true);
        }

        WC_AJAX :: get_refreshed_fragments();
    } else {

        $data = array(
            'error' => true,
            'product_url' => apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_redirect_after_error', get_permalink($product_id), $product_id));

        echo wp_send_json($data);
    }

    wp_die();
} 

add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');
```

And here is my jQuery for checkbox and Ajax:

```
var isChecked = false;
jQuery("body").on("change input", ".products li.product #add-to-cart-all", function(){
    var len = jQuery(".products li.product #add-to-cart-all").filter(":checked").length;
    if(len > 0){
        jQuery(".bulk-add-to-cart").css("display","block");
    }
    else{
        jQuery(".bulk-add-to-cart").css("display","none");
    } 
});


jQuery("body").on("click", ".bulk-add-to-cart a", function(){
    
    jQuery(".products li.product #add-to-cart-all").filter(":checked").each(function(){
        // alert(jQuery(this).val());

            var product_id = jQuery(this).val();
            var qty = jQuery(this).closest("li").find(".qty").val();
            //alert(qty);
            var data = {
                action: "woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart",
                product_id: product_id,
                quantity: qty,
            };
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: wc_add_to_cart_params.ajax_url,
                data: data,
                beforeSend: function (response) {
                   //alert("before");
                },
                complete: function (response) {
                    //alert("Complete");
                }, 
                success: function (response) { 
                     if (response.error & response.product_url) {
                         console.log("add");
                        /* window.location = response.product_url;
                        return; */ 
                    } else { 
                        alert("else");
                        // $(document.body).trigger("added_to_cart", [response.fragments, response.cart_hash, $thisbutton]);
                    } 
                }, 
            }); 

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I make it with my self here is the the code.

u can check it there as example...

[Example website](https://myprojectstaging.net/development/firstline/store/)

> script

```
let base_url = "https://myprojectstaging.net/development/firstline"; 
function multiAddToCart( productsData ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            'action': 'multi_add_to_cart',
            'items' : Object.assign({}, productsData)
        },
        success : function(response) {
            $(document.body).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh'); // Refresh cart fragments
            console.log('ajax-response',response);
            $(".products li.product #add-to-cart-all").filter(":checked").each(function() {
                $(this).prop('checked', false);
            });
        },
        error : function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}

$('.bulk-add-to-cart a').on('click', function() {
    var productsData = [];

    $(".products li.product #add-to-cart-all").filter(":checked").each(function() {
        var product_id = jQuery(this).val();
        var qty = jQuery(this).closest("li").find(".qty").val();
        productsData.push({'id': product_id, 'qty': qty});
    });
    
    console.log('product-data',productsData); 

    multiAddToCart( productsData );
});
```

> function.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_multi_add_to_cart', 'multi_ajax_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_multi_add_to_cart', 'multi_ajax_add_to_cart');
function multi_ajax_add_to_cart() {
    if (isset($_POST['items']) ) {
        $item_keys = array();

        foreach( $_POST['items'] as $item ) {
            if( isset($item['id']) ) {
                $item_qty  = isset($item['qty']) && $item['qty'] > 1 ? $item['qty'] : 1;
                $item_keys[] = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($item['id'], $item_qty);
            }
        }
        echo json_encode($item_keys);
    }
    die();
}
```